# How to add test cases to TFS via REST API

Tags: rest-api, tfs

I'm implementing a library to export/synchronize test cases into TFS automaticaly during test run. One of my requirements is that I need to use `NodeJS`, so I decided to use TFS REST API. In my code I'm using `azure-devops-node-api` lib. I can connect and get different elements, but I'm unable to add test cases.

I've found on the web that a TestCase is a kind of WorkItem and as WI should be added. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to add one with `azure-devops-node-api`.

I also tried to send manually constructed `json`, but no luck with finding proper url to send as I'm always getting:

> Error: {"statusCode":404,"body":"Page not found."

My example request:

```
  request.post({
        url: 'https://<url>/tfs/<default collection maybe?>/<project>/_apis/wit/workItems/test%20case',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':'Basic ' + this.encodePat('<my auth token>')
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
        requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
        agent: false,//add when working with https sites
        json: rq
    },function (response, err, body){

        if (err) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));

        console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
        console.log('Response:',response)
    });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or if `azure-devops-node-api` is able to add WorkItems?

Comment: I'd suggest starting here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 and working with Postman or a similar tool until you have the connection information and URL structure confirmed. You'll also want to make sure you've got the correct API version information for your TFS version

Comment: I've found my error - I missed '$' sign before WorkItemType in URL :) so proper path is:

       /_apis/wit/workItems/$test%20case?api-version=2.0

Comment: For completeness, please post the information as an answer to the question, then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

I've found my error - I missed '$' sign before WorkItemType in URL. So proper path is: `/_apis/wit/workItems/$test%20case?api-version=2.0`